# How can I set the path to Instruments on Appium?

Tags: ios, instruments, appium

I'm trying to run Appium for an iOS application, but it seems that the path to instruments is invalid. How can I set it? Is there an environment variable I should use? Or some argument? Even I could change that in the source code it would be useful for me :)

Here's the relevant part of the log I receive from Appium:

```
info: instruments is: 
info: [INSTSERVER] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: Spawning instruments with command:  -t /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/app/uiauto/Automation.tracetemplate /var/folders/rd/z5t93lfj0cx0wm2_hqmthnkr0000gn/T/TestApp.app -e UIASCRIPT /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/app/uiauto/bootstrap.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After some digging in the code it appears Appium takes its "Instruments" path by using the command `xcrun -find instruments`.

xcrun itself has cache, so if you changed/removed xcode you should probably run
`xcrun -kill-cache -find instruments`

This will clear the cache, but will not necessarily point xcrun to the right path. In order to do so you should add the environment variable `DEVELOPER_DIR` to point to the Xcode developer directory, e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/Xcode.app` to select which version of Xcode you'd like to use with appium.